# CheckBox is used instead of Edit in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have trying to Edit and Update my GridView in bulk.
I have generated a `CheckBox` in the first column of my `GridView`. It works something like this:
If I check a particular row in the `GridView`, the row gets editable. 
Like this I can check as many rows I want to edit the `GridView`.
I have given a universal button called UPDATE, once after editing all the rows, and click on this button, the `GridView` is updated looping in each row checking for CheckBox.Check.

The issue I am facing here is that, when I click on any `CheckBox` in the `GridView` row, I am not getting `TextBox`.
I am trying to convert `Label` to `TextBox` on checking a `CheckBox` in the `GridView`.

So when I check a row, the text corresponding to `Label` template for that cell goes invisible according to my program, but fails to get the `TextBox` with the value of that cell.

The code I have tried is this:

```
protected void OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isUpdateVisible = false;
        CheckBox chk = (sender as CheckBox);
        if (chk.ID == "chkAll")
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView3.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    row.Cells[0].Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault().Checked = chk.Checked;
                }
            }
        }
        CheckBox chkAll = (GridView3.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkAll") as CheckBox);
        chkAll.Checked = true;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView3.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                bool isChecked = row.Cells[0].Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault().Checked;
                for (int i = 3; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    row.Cells[i].Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault().Visible = !isChecked;
                    if (row.Cells[i].Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().Count > 0)//this condition is not satisfying when I debug the program. what is wrong in this line?
                    {
                        row.Cells[i].Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault().Visible = isChecked;
                    }
                    if (isChecked && !isUpdateVisible)
                    {
                        isUpdateVisible = true;
                    }
                    if (!isChecked)
                    {
                        chkAll.Checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        UpdateGrid.Visible = isUpdateVisible;
    }
```

The aspx code is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
DataKeyNames="Location_Profile_Name">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="OnCheckedChanged" />
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="OnCheckedChanged" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location_Profile_Name" SortExpression="Location_Profile_Name">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location_Profile_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Home_Profile" SortExpression="Label10">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Home_Profile") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Home_Profile") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns></asp:GridView>
```

I have commented the issue I am facing in the program above. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are mixing to approaches, the Template approach (ItemTemplate, EditTemplate), and some Code-Behind approach (doing things hard-coded in code behind).
For your cenario, i sugest do it in code-behind, to get full control of the situation.
i addapted your code to explain my sugestion. Here is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="OnCheckedChanged" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="OnCheckedChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location_Profile_Name" SortExpression="Location_Profile_Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location_Profile_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Home_Profile" SortExpression="Label10">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Home_Profile") %>'></asp:Label>
                <%--Here are the controls that edit this row, we will handle this on code-behind--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Home_Profile") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="save" runat="server" Visible="false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The "EditTemplate" was deleted, YOU will handle your own edit template.

```
        protected void OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //... Your code ...
        // Here we find the controls tha we will handle
        CheckBox chkAll = (GridView3.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkAll") as CheckBox);
        chkAll.Checked = true;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView3.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
                Label Label2 = (Label)row.FindControl("Label2");
                TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox1");
                Button btnSave = (Button)row.FindControl("btnSave");

                //GridView3.SetEditRow(row.RowIndex);
                if (CheckBox1 != null)
                {
                    if (CheckBox1.Checked)
                    {

                        if (TextBox1 != null && Label2 != null)
                        {
                            // Shows your "Edit Template"
                            btnSave.Visible = true;
                            Label2.Visible = false;
                            TextBox1.Visible = true;
                            TextBox1.Text = Label2.Text;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

for now, you have the control of situation :)

Comment: would be interesting use some UpdatePanel to provide some "ajax" behaviour, if you need it, we can discuss it

Answer (score 0):

see this post [Edit Update Delete Multiple Records](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/05/edit-multiple-records-gridview-checkbox.html)

basically you need to add in your gridview

```
 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" 
              AutoPostBack="true" 
         OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged"/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and code behind:

```
protected void chkSelect_CheckedChanged
                        (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chkTest = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow grdRow = (GridViewRow)chkTest.NamingContainer;
        TextBox txtname = (TextBox)grdRow.FindControl("txtName");

        if (chkTest.Checked)
        {
            txtname.ReadOnly = false;                               
        }
        else
        {
            txtname.ReadOnly = true;                                
        }
    }
```

if you familiar with Jquery you can easily enable the fields also in client side

Answer (score 0):

Since AutoGenerateEditButton = false, therefore there should be no  for Home_Profile. The `TextBox` template for Home_Profile should be written within  and the visibility should be set to false.

The aspx code is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Home_Profile" SortExpression="Label10">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Home_Profile") %>'></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Home_Profile") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score -1):

i don't have the code for the way i previously did it, here is a little example using similar logic that what you did, i hope it helps

here is an working example doing it the way you did it

Code Behind

> ```
> public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
> protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     if (!IsPostBack)
>     {
>         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
>         dt.Columns.Add("Name");
>
>         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
>         {
>             DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
>             dr[0] = "Test " + i;
>             dt.Rows.Add(dr);
>         }
>
>         rptITem.DataSource = dt;
>         rptITem.DataBind();
>     }
>
> }
>
>
> protected void UpdateCB(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     foreach (RepeaterItem Item in rptITem.Items)
>     {
>         CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)Item.FindControl("cbTest");
>         TextBox tb = (TextBox)Item.FindControl("tbTest");
>         Label lb = (Label)Item.FindControl("lbTest");
>         tb.Visible = cb.Checked;
>         lb.Visible = !cb.Checked;
>     }
> }
>
> protected void UpdateAll(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     foreach (RepeaterItem Item in rptITem.Items)
>     {
>         CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)Item.FindControl("cbTest");
>         TextBox tb = (TextBox)Item.FindControl("tbTest");
>         Label lb = (Label)Item.FindControl("lbTest");
>         cb.Checked = true;
>         tb.Visible = true;
>         lb.Visible = false;
>     }
> } }
> ```

Aspx Code

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptITem" runat="server">
      <HeaderTemplate>
      <div style="border:1px solid black">
        <div style="width:50px; float:left"><asp:CheckBox ID="cbAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="UpdateAll" /></div>
        <div style="width:200px; float:left;">Name</div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
      </div>
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>

        <div style="width:50px; float:left"><asp:CheckBox ID="cbTest" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="UpdateCB" /></div>
        <div style="width:200px; float:left;"><asp:Label ID="lbTest" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' ></asp:Label></div>
        <div style="width:200px; float:left;"><asp:TextBox ID="tbTest" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox></div>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <SeparatorTemplate>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
      </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can pls add the code that you have tried. It would be helpful

Comment: This was a while back, ill try make a small example for you